# Using java.lang.Class<?> in a switch statement

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use a `Class<?>` in an if statement, like the following:

```
public static Model get(Class<? extends FooBase> type, long id )
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case FooType.class:
            return new Foo(id);
        break;
    }
}
```

However, the line: `case FooType.class:` is giving me the error,

`Expected Class<capture<? extends FooBase>> , given Class<FooType.class>`.

`FooType` does implement the `FooBase` interface.

Is it not possible to do a switch on `Class<?>` values?

Comment: Extract the class name String and switch on that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use a `Class` as the expression for your switch statement, according to [the JLS, Section 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> **The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.**

You can compare the `Class` objects directly.  Because there is only one `Class` object per actual class, the `==` operator works here.

```
if (type == FooType.class)
```

Comment: Can I still do a normal `==` comparison, like `if type == FooType.class` in the above code, where `type` is `Class<? extends FooBase>` and `FooType` implements `FooBase`?

Comment: Yes, you can compare `Class` objects directly.

Comment: In many cases what you really want to use when testing types is `instanceof` rather than `==`.

Comment: @keshlam Only for testing if an object is an instance of a class, not whether `Class` objects are the same.

Comment: [`isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) can be used to tell whether a class is "equal to or a subclass" of another, like `instanceof` but without needing an object.